# New columns based off existing column and column located next to it

Tags: r, dplyr, melt

My dataframe looks like this

```
ID t1 obs1 t2 obs2 t3 obs3
1  0  a    11 d    0  g
2  0  b    13 e    11 i
3  0  c    0  f    0  h
```

I need to make sure each ID has at least one t above 10 (delete row if not). Then, I want to save the lowest t value above 10, but also save the corresponding obs in new columns. (The complicated part about my question is that the lowest t above 10 could be in any column). The corresponding obs to some t is located in the next column, so that helps. So my resulting data frame would look like this:

```
ID t1 obs1 t2 obs2 t3 obs3 lowesttabove10 correspondingobs
1  0  a    11 d    0  g    11             d
2  0  b    13 e    11 i    11             i
```

Answer (score 4):

With data.table, go to long format:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
dat = melt(DT, measure.vars = patterns("^t\\d+$", "^obs\\d+$"), value.name = c("t", "obs"))
setorder(dat, ID, variable)

#    ID variable  t obs
# 1:  1        1  0   a
# 2:  1        2 11   d
# 3:  1        3  0   g
# 4:  2        1  0   b
# 5:  2        2 13   e
# 6:  2        3 11   i
# 7:  3        1  0   c
# 8:  3        2  0   f
# 9:  3        3  0   h
```

Find max value per group and mark groups to keep:

```
IDDT = dat[order(-t), 
  .(max.variable = first(variable), max.t = first(t), max.obs = first(obs))
, by=ID]
IDDT[, keep := max.t > 10]

#    ID max.variable max.t max.obs  keep
# 1:  2            2    13       e  TRUE
# 2:  1            2    11       d  TRUE
# 3:  3            1     0       c FALSE
```

Find min value over 10 per kept group using a rolling update join:

```
IDDT[(keep), c("my.variable", "my.t", "my.obs") := {
  m = .(ID = ID, t_thresh = 10)
  dat[m, on=.(ID, t = t_thresh), roll=-Inf, .(x.variable, x.t, x.obs)]
}]

#    ID max.variable max.t max.obs  keep my.variable my.t my.obs
# 1:  2            2    13       e  TRUE           3   11      i
# 2:  1            2    11       d  TRUE           2   11      d
# 3:  3            1     0       c FALSE          NA   NA     NA
```

I would stop here, with the main data in long format `dat` and the `ID` level variables in the separate table `IDDT`. To filter `dat` to groups that should be kept: `dat[IDDT[(keep), .(ID)], on=.(ID)]`. See `?data.table` and the other intro materials mentioned when you load the package for details on the syntax.

See `?dcast` if you insist on going back to wide.

Answer (score 3):

Using base R:

Drop all rows with no t-values above 10:

```
df1 <- df1[rowSums(df1[, grepl("^t", colnames(df1))] >10) > 0, ]
```

Determine the group that contains the lowest value above 10 and then retrieve values:

```
df1$group <- apply(df1[grepl("^t", names(df1))], 1, function(x) which(x == min(x[x > 10])))
df1 <- cbind(df1, do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 
                                        function(x) setNames(df1[x, paste0(c("t", "obs"), df1$group[x])],
                                                             c("lowesttabove10", "correspondingobs")))))

> df1
  ID t1 obs1 t2 obs2 t3 obs3 group lowesttabove10 correspondingobs
1  1  0    a 11    d  0    g     2             11                d
2  2  0    b 13    e 11    i     3             11                i
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach is not neat , but still works, You can try it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)
df1=melt(df,id='ID')

df2=df1%>%group_by(ID)%>%filter(value>10)%>%dplyr::slice(which.min(value))%>%na.omit()

> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID variable value
  <int>   <fctr> <chr>
1     1       t2    11
2     2       t3    11


df2$variable=as.character(df2$variable)
C=as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", df2$variable))
df=df[df$ID%in%df2$ID,]
for (i in 1:length(C)){
DF1=df[i,str_detect(names(df),as.character(C[i]))]
names(DF1)=c('lowesttabove10 ','correspondingobs')
if (i ==1 ){DFF=DF1}else{DFF=rbind(DFF,DF1)}
}
cbind(df,DFF)

  ID t1 obs1 t2 obs2 t3 obs3 lowesttabove10  correspondingobs
1  1  0    a 11    d  0    g              11                d
2  2  0    b 13    e 11    i              11                i
```

Comment: reshape is built to play nice with plyr, while tidyr is for dplyr, fyi.

Comment: Just noticed: you need to convert df1$value to numeric. With character, you would see `"2" > 10` inside the filter. Also, it looks like your second step should/could be `left_join(df2, df)`?

Comment: @Frank Yes you are right , and `'1'>10` on my side return `FALSE`

Answer (score 2):

Solution uses `dplyr` and `tidyr` in one pipeline. `dt` is the original data, while `dt2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(t_group, t_value, starts_with("t")) %>%
  gather(obs_group, obs_value, starts_with("obs")) %>%
  filter(gsub("t", "", t_group) == gsub("obs", "", obs_group)) %>%
  filter(t_value >= 10) %>%
  filter(t_value == min(t_value)) %>%
  select(ID, lowesttabove10 = t_value, correspondingobs = obs_value) %>%
  inner_join(dt, by = "ID") %>%
  select(colnames(dt), lowesttabove10, correspondingobs)

df2
  ID t1 obs1 t2 obs2 t3 obs3 lowesttabove10 correspondingobs
1  1  0    a 11    d  0    g             11                d
2  2  0    b 13    e 11    i             11                i
```

Data:

```
dt <- read.table(text = "ID t1 obs1 t2 obs2 t3 obs3
1  0  a    11 d    0  g
                 2  0  b    13 e    11 i
                 3  0  c    0  f    0  h",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you know why I am getting this error? Error: is_dictionaryish(x) is not TRUE

Comment: Not sure. Try to get the latest `dplyr` or `tidyverse` package. If the error still occurs, you can use the approach in base R or `data.table` as others suggested.